# Variable in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In order to made my jenkins pipeline definition file more customizable, I try to use a maximum of variables.

When I try to use variable in **mail** or **step** instruction jenkins throw this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, error, fileExists, git, input, isUnix, load, mail, node, parallel, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, retry, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withCredentials, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws]
```

This is my jenkins pipleline definition file:

```
#!groovy
node {

    //Define job context constants
    def projectName = "JenkinsPipelineTest"
    def notificationEmailRecipients = "aaa@domain.com"
    def notificationEmailSender = "bbb@domain.com"
    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

    //Handle error that can occur in every satge
    try {

            //Some others stage...

            stage 'Finalization'
            step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '*.zip, *.tar, *.exe, *.html', excludes: null])
            step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: ${notificationEmailRecipients}, sendToIndividuals: false])
    }
    catch (err) {
        //Set built state to error
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

        //Send error notification mail
        mail body: ${err},
        charset: 'UTF-8',
        from: ${notificationEmailSender},
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        replyTo: ${notificationEmailSender},
        subject: '"${projectName}" meet an error',
        to: ${notificationEmailRecipients}

        throw err
    }
}
```

It's normal or it's me that have an error in my definition file ?

Answer (score 6):

It was my fault!

I have made a confusion between variable in string and variable and Groovy code:

Code:

```
step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: ${notificationEmailRecipients}, sendToIndividuals: false])
```

Must be:

```
step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: notificationEmailRecipients, sendToIndividuals: false])
```

Here I must not use the **${}** because i'm in the Groovy code and not in a string.

Second error, the mail body must be:

```
mail body: "Error: ${err}"
```

And not:

```
mail body: ${err}
```

Because **err** here is a IOException class instance and not a string.

So final code is:

```
#!groovy
node {

    //Define job context constants
    def projectName = "JenkinsPipelineTest"
    def notificationEmailRecipients = "aaa@domain.com"
    def notificationEmailSender = "bbb@domain.com"
    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

    //Handle error that can occur in every satge
    try {

            //Some others stage...

            stage 'Finalization'
            step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '*.zip, *.tar, *.exe, *.html', excludes: null])
            step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: notificationEmailRecipients, sendToIndividuals: false])
    }
    catch (err) {
        //Set built state to error
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"

        //Send error notification mail
        mail body: "Error: ${err}",
        charset: 'UTF-8',
        from: notificationEmailSender,
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        replyTo: notificationEmailSender,
        subject: '${projectName} meet an error',
        to: notificationEmailRecipients

        throw err
    }
}
```

Hope this answer will help.